# Problems Saving NSMutableArray with custom objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nscoding

I have a class called `CurrentUser`, which holds a `NSMutableArray` called `listOfFriends`. This `listOfFriends` holds objects from the class `Friends`.

Both `CurrentUser` and `Friend` classes have the `NSCoding` protocols handled.
The `Friend` object has a property called `userImg`, which is a `UIImage`.
There's just one problem. 
When I try to load the `lisOfFriends`, the Friends don't come with their `UIImages`.

If I save any friend, and try to load it back again, it comes with the `UIImage` with no problem. But if the object is inside the `listOfFriends`, it doesn't come with the `UIImage`, but all other informations are loaded correctly.

My question then is: How can I store and load a `NSMutableArray` with custom objects?
Declaration of the friendList:

**CurrentUser.h**

```
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *FriendsList;
```

**CurrentUser.m**

```
  - (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:username forKey:@"username"];
    [encoder encodeObject:FriendsList forKey:@"FriendsList"];
    //testing direct friend saving
    [encoder encodeObject:[FriendsList objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"testFriend"];
    [encoder encodeObject:_userPSW forKey:@"userpassword"];
    [encoder encodeObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(userImg) forKey:@"userImg"];
    [encoder encodeObject:userID forKey:@"userID"];
    [encoder encodeObject:groups forKey:@"groups"];
    [encoder encodeObject:_email forKey:@"email"];

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    currentUser *returnUser = [[currentUser alloc] init];
    returnUser.username = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"username"];
    returnUser.email = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"email"];
    //testing direct friend loading
    Friend *testFriend = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"testFriend"];
    returnUser.userPSW = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"userpassword"];
    returnUser.userImg = [UIImage imageWithData:[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"userImg"]];
    returnUser.FriendsList = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"FriendsList"];
    returnUser.userID = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"userID"];
    returnUser.groups = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"groups"];

    return returnUser;
}
```

**Friend.m**

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder{  
    [encoder encodeObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(userImg) forKey:@"friendIMG"];
    [encoder encodeObject:username forKey:@"friendUN"];
    [encoder encodeObject:userID forKey:@"friendID"];

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder{
    Friend *obj = [[Friend alloc]init];
    obj.username = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"friendUN"];
    obj.userImg = [UIImage imageWithData:[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"friendIMG"]];
    obj.userID = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"friendID"];
    return obj;

}
```

This is the object I have to save and load the CurrentUser, It's called "Configurations".
Configurations.h

```
#import "currentUser.h"
@interface configurations : NSObject
- (currentUser*)loadCustomObject;
- (void)saveCustomObject:(currentUser *)object;

@end
```

**Configurations.m**

```
#import "configurations.h"

@implementation configurations
- (void)saveCustomObject:(currentUser *)object {
    NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:object];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:encodedObject forKey:@"lastUser"];
    [defaults synchronize];

}

- (currentUser*)loadCustomObject {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *encodedObject = [defaults objectForKey:@"lastUser"];
    currentUser *object = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObject];
    return object;
}
@end
```

This is how I'm loading the CurrentUser.

```
saver = [[configurations alloc]init];
currentUser *tmpUser = [saver loadCustomObject];
thisUser = [currentUser instance];

static dispatch_once_t once;
dispatch_once(&once, ^ {
        if(tmpUser != nil){
            if(![tmpUser.username isEqualToString:@""]){


            for(Friend *savedFriend in tmpUser.FriendsList)
            {
                [thisUser addFriend:savedFriend];
            }
                thisUser.username = tmpUser.username;
                thisUser.email = tmpUser.email;
                thisUser.userID = tmpUser.userID;
                thisUser.userPSW = tmpUser.userPSW;
                thisUser.userImg = tmpUser.userImg;
});
```

Comment: Where do you define the FriendsList property?

Comment: By the way in objective-c it's standard to capitalize class names, but not property/variable names.

Comment: I define the FriendsList property in the CurrentUser.h like:
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *FriendsList;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `initWithCoder:` methods are incorrect. They need to be in the following pattern:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super init]; // or [super initWithCoder:decoder] if appropriate
    if (self) {
        _someIvar = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"someKey"];
        _someOtherIvar = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"someOtherKey"];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Fixing the `initWithCoder:` method for both your `CurrentUser` and `Friend` classes will help a lot.

CurrentUser:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _username = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"username"];
        _email = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"email"];
        //testing direct friend loading
        Friend *testFriend = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"testFriend"];
        _userPSW = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"userpassword"];
        _userImg = [UIImage imageWithData:[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"userImg"]];
        _FriendsList = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"FriendsList"];
        _userID = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"userID"];
        _groups = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"groups"];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Friend:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _username = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"friendUN"];
        _userImg = [UIImage imageWithData:[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"friendIMG"]];
        _userID = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"friendID"];
    }

    return self;
}
```